# What is --reporter spec in mocha.opts file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I am currently learning about implementing test cases for loopback framework using `mocha, chai and supertest` from this [github](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-mixins/blob/master/test/mocha.opts). But I got stuck understanding this line `--reporter spec` in `mocha.opts` file.

Appreciate your guidance about reporter spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It specifies the output to use for report.

http://ricostacruz.com/mocha/#reporters